# Matlab timeit equivalent in Python for scripts

Tags: python, matlab, timing

In Matlab there is

> "timeit(F), which measures the typical time (in seconds) required to run the function specified by the function handle F that takes no input argument."

This method returns the median of (I think 13) runs of the function.

Having looked at the methods `time` and `timeit` in Python, I can't quite find anything that will let me call from an IPython console, time my script (not function) a number of times, and return either an average or median.

Is there an easy way to do this? or at least time 1 execution, whereby I can make my own loop and average?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to look at this link and consider the `%timeit` magic from IPython

[link](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/gist/damontallen/5978528)

---

Example:

Say you define a function you want to test:

```
def logtest1(N):
tr=0.
for i in xrange(N):
    T= 40. + 10.*random()
    tr = tr + -log(random())/T

from timeit import Timer, timeit, repeat
runningtime = repeat("logtest1(int(10e5))", setup="from __main__ import logtest1", repeat=5, number=1)
print (runningtime)
```

That will run my function `logtest1(int(10e5))` 1 time and store the time in the list `runningtime` then it will repeat the same thing 5 times and store the results in the same list. You can then take the average of the median of that list.

Comment: Having looked at it, there is no specification about running scripts from this? Or would I be implementing this within the script?

Comment: Yes, you should do from within the script. Or at least load the script into IPython, make it a function and run it like that. Another alternative would be chaining the Ipython magics %timeit %run test.py (you can customize the timeit magic options if needed)

Comment: I used `%timeit -n10 %run test` which runs for 10 loops and 3(default, but changed by adding `-r` after `-n`) times, and takes the best of the 3 runs of 10